# Understanding buildscript

Tags: java, gradle, tomcat

How to understand following `build.gradle` script:

```
buildscript 
{
       repositories {
             jcenter()
       }
       dependencies {
             classpath 'com.bmuschko:gradle-tomcat-plugin:2.4.1'
       }
}
```

According to my understanding `repositories{}` defines `dependencies{}` locations.

I see that `dependencies` wrapped inside of `buildscript` defines tomcat plugin. But what is idea to do so in such strange way?

Whole script:

```
apply plugin: 'com.bmuschko.tomcat'
apply plugin: 'eclipse-wtp'


buildscript {
       repositories {
             jcenter()
       }
       dependencies {
             classpath 'com.bmuschko:gradle-tomcat-plugin:2.4.1'
       }
}


dependencies {
         def tomcatVersion = '8.0.46'
         tomcat "org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:${tomcatVersion}",
         "org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-logging-juli:${tomcatVersion}",
         "org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-jasper:${tomcatVersion}"
         api 'org.apache.commons:commons-math3:3.6.1'
}


tomcat {
         httpPort = 8080
         enableSSL = true
         contextPath = '/library-spring'
}
```

Comment: Just like a project code, gradle build script also programmable, dependencies in buildscript is depedencies for the buildscript. see https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/organizing_gradle_projects.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nowadays almost all plugins for Gradle are published to the [Gradle Plugin Portal](https://plugins.gradle.org/), so Gradle knows how to resolve them and you can simply use the `plugins` block to define them in your build script:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.bmuschko.tomcat' version '2.5'
}
```

In earlier days of Gradle, plugins could only be distributed in the same way as any other library, e.g. using a public Maven repository like Maven Central or Bintray. This way they could be resolved in the same way as other libraries, using the `dependencies` block to define **what** to resolve and using the `repositories` block to define **where** to resolve.

The problem of using the regular `repositories` and `dependencies` blocks is, that those dependencies are loaded when the build script gets evaluated. But to evaluate the build script, the plugin libraries are required to be on the classpath.

For this reason, the `buildscript` block was introduced to load all the dependencies before evaluating the actual build script. This is also the reason why the `buildscript` block should always go first in a build script:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        // where to resolve dependencies of your build script
    }
    dependencies {
        // what dependencies to resolve for your build script
    }
}

repositories {
    // where to resolve dependencies of your project code
}

dependencies {
    // what dependencies to resolve for your project code
}
```